# User specific host file

Tags: macos, terminal, network, sudo, hosts

I would like to add a user specific host file on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.5) to a users home directory and have this be checked in addition to `/etc/hosts` when resolving domain names.

I found a similar answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts). This answer was a flat no because that individual did not have superuser privileges. This is not the case for me because I do in fact have superuser privileges.

I found another answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts), but that doesn't seem to work on my machine. This answer involves setting the `HOSTALIASES` environment variable to `~/.hosts`, but no addition to the `~/.hosts` file ever had any implications in my web browser, which is the goal of me wanting to create a user specific host file.

NOTE: After reading through a bit of the man pages of bash, the correct environment variable on mac that the second answer needs is `HOSTFILE`. However, this still didn't affect anything. Thoughts on this?

EDIT: This is for a single user environment as MrWonderful suggested. However, I would like for the hosts setting of one user to be unaffected but another user.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm still curious as to what benefit this might provide that couldn't be realized through programatic means.

Comment: `HOSTALIASES=$HOME/hosts sudo -E dtruss ping foobar` shows the only file opened is `/etc/hosts`. `HOSTFILE=$HOME/hosts` has the same result. The `hosts(5)` man page states only `/etc/hosts` is read. The `hostname(7)` man page states `HOSTALIASES` is used. Ugh, more broken Apple software.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60549/etc-hosts-file-refer-to-another-configuration-file

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are managing a single-user environment, such as a shared MacBook, you could potentially have each user's *.bashrc* copy a base *hosts* file, then append their custom one to the end of it.  For example:

```
sudo cp /etc/common_hosts /etc/hosts  
sudo cat ~/my_hosts >> /etc/hosts
```

This would effectively give every user their own custom additions to the *hosts* file.  You can make it so a password isn't needed for these sudo commands by using the *sudo visudo* command and adding them to the allowed commands.  Here are some examples from the bottom of my *sudoers* file:

```
# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Under OS X, the /etc/hosts file is apparently dynamically read, so the net services would not need to be restarted.

```
mbp-c17189:~ root# ping goog
ping: cannot resolve goog: Unknown host
mbp-c17189:~ root# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=4306.507 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 50.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 4306.507/4306.507/4306.507/0.000 ms
mbp-c17189:~ root# echo 172.217.4.238     goog>>/etc/hosts
mbp-c17189:~ root# ping goog
PING goog (172.217.4.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=43.639 ms
^C
--- goog ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 43.639/43.914/44.189/0.275 ms
mbp-c17189:~ root#
```

Comment: So, how do you handle it when two people are logged in simultaneously?

Comment: My answer would only apply to a single-user-at-a-time scenario, like on a Macbook, for instance.  In a shared environment, this would not work well / at all.

Comment: @Allan - What is your real goal?  Perhaps if you gave a more concrete example it would facilitate a deeper understanding of the problem domain.  Especially why different users would need different names or IP addresses for some entries.

Comment: This is close to what I was after. I really wanted to leave the main hosts file alone so that the hosts setting for each user would apply only to them, but this is helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Not my goal...I just don't see this as a viable solution given that you would have to give sudo access to users potentially with no password.  What's going to prompt them for the password every time the host file is to be edited?

Comment: @Allan - not true, /etc/hosts is read dynamically

Comment: @Allan - using 'visudo' you can list typically sudo commands that don't require sudo or a password.  It wouldn't require the users needing the root password at all.